# Consumer Group in Chronice Queue

Tags: chronicle, chronicle-queue, chronicle-map

Is it possible to use groups in chronicle consumer, so that multiple instances watching the queue whose message is consumed once for every message if these instances are grouped together?

Answer (score 0):

You can add padding to the excerpt in the queue to hold the worker to process the message.

To make this dynamic, you can make it 0 for example and each worker use a CAS from 0 to their id to assign as each worker is available. This will succeed for only one worker and record which one picked up the work. i.e. it is the reader which writes it's id atomically. This only takes a fraction of a microsecond.